# Append HTML inside nested classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to loop through classes and append some text to an HTML element. I'm working with the following HTML (example case):

```
<div class="question">
    <div class="title">
        <strong>Here's the question title.</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice1.</div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice2.</div>
</div>
<div class="question">
    <div class="title">
        <strong>Here's the question title.</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice1.</div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice2.</div>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is loop through each question on the page, see if the title matches some string, then append some text based on that statement. I have the following:

```
$('.question').each(function() {

    var title = $(this).find('.title').innerHTML;

    $('.choice').each(function() {

        var span = document.createElement("span");

        if (title == "someString")
        {
            span.className = "someClass";
        }
        else
        {
            span.className = "someOtherClass";
        }

        var text = document.createTextNode("text");
        span.appendChild(text);

        $(this).appendChild(span);
    });

    // put this in to see if outer loop was working
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
});
```

The text will change color based on what the title is, hence the different CSS classes. But it doesn't seem to be doing anything, not even appending the text to each choice. The background color does change to orange, and Chrome isn't throwing any errors from the script in the developer tools, so I'm totally lost. Can anyone help?

Comment: CAn you post a live code? (jsfiddle)

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9RZAw/1/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny that's perfect! i was just about to post a Fiddle that doesn't work. is the only thing you changed the line pulling the title?

Comment: @aquemini and the append child at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

You can get the title like this:

```
var title = $(this).find('.title strong').text();
```

Here you're confusing jquery with native javascript, `$(this)` is a jquery object so you cannot use `appendChild()` here's how you change that:

```
$(this).get(0).appendChild(span);
```

Or you can use jQuery directly:

```
$(this).append(span);
```

Comment: great! this works for my example. i tried to apply it to my actual code, and i can't get it to work. am i missing something stupid? http://jsfiddle.net/9RZAw/7/

Comment: Yap a bit of trouble with your selectors I fixed them line 3 and 6 http://jsfiddle.net/9RZAw/13/

Answer (score 2):

Using Arun P Johny's fiddle, I've updated a few things;

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9RZAw/2/)

The following are the important changes;

```
var title = $.trim($(this).find('.title').text());

    $(this).find('.choice').each(function () {...
```

Changing `$('.choice')` to `$(this).find('.choice')` because you only want to change the elements within that question, not every `choice` element on the page.

and `find('.title').innerHTML;` to `find('.title').text());` because you only want to match the text within that div, not the html as well.

Comment: great! this works for my example. i tried to apply it to my actual code, and i can't get it to work. am i missing something stupid? http://jsfiddle.net/9RZAw/7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9RZAw/12/ - `$('.mg-column3.opponents')` instead of `$('.mg-column3 opponents')` as well as removing `index` from `$(this).find('.gamequestion').text();`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/NUJay/1/)

jQuery ( Comment free code in the jsfiddle ):

```
// On document ready...
$(function () {

    // Geat each title element...
    $('.title').each(function () {

            // Points to each title element as defined above
        var title = $(this),
            // Get all siblings of title element(s)
            choices = title.siblings(),
            // Ternary if statement. Equivalent to if ( X ) {} else {}
            myClass = title.text().trim() === "Here's the question title." ? "someClass" : "someOtherClass";

        // Make a span element...
        $('<span />', {
            class: myClass,         // Give it a class
            text: " Appended text"  // Give it some text
        }).appendTo(choices);       // Append the span to each .choice element

    });

});
```

Html:

```
<div class="question">
    <div class="title"><strong>Here's the question title.</strong></div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice1.</div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice2.</div>
</div>

<div class="question">
    <div class="title"><strong>Here's the question title.</strong></div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice1.</div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice2.</div>
</div>

<div class="question">
    <div class="title"><strong>Here's title.</strong></div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice1.</div>
    <div class="choice">Here's choice2.</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.someClass {
    color: red;
}
.someOtherClass {
    color: green;
}

.question { margin: 10px 0px; }
```